# ¿Cómo podría cambiar el color de n caracteres de un String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Mi pregunta es la del título. Tengo una tabla en la que meto unos Strings dentro y querría saber como podría hacer para que por ejemplo los 3 primeros caracteres del String aparezcan en rojo.
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/comun/directivas.jsp"%>

<div id="cierrePresupuestoDialog" style="display: none">

    <ul class="fila fila-1">
        <li> <b><***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.mensajeIntroduccion" /> </b></li>
    </ul>   

    <div class="separador"></div>

<!-- tabla resumen de las validaciones que se muestra al confirmar el cierre del presupuesto-->
    <table  width="500" style=’table-layout:fixed’>
        <tr>
                <td> <***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.cabeceraTipo" /></td>
                <td> <***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.estado" /></td>
                <td> <***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.cabeceraDepartamento" /></td>
                <td> <***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.cabeceraNumeroEntSec" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
                <td><***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.ingresos" /></td>
                <td><***:mensaje code="titulo.presupuesto.listado" /></td>
                <td><***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.validado" /></td>
                <td> ${lineaIngresosPresupuestos}</td>
              </tr>
        <tr id="lineaIngresosDepartamentoGestion">
                <td><***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.ingresos" /></td>
                <td class="descripcionConError"><cixtec:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.gestion" /></td>
                <td><***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.validado" /></td>
                <td class="descripcionConError"> ${lineaIngresosGestion}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.gastos" /></td>
                <td><***:mensaje code="titulo.presupuesto.listado" /></td>
                <td><***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.validado" /></td>
                <td> ${lineaGastosValidado}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="lineaGastosSinValidar">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="descripcionConError"><***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.sinValidar" /></td>
                <td class="descripcionConError">${lineaGastosSinvalidar} </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="lineaGastosConErrores">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="descripcionConError"><***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.conErrores" /></td>
                <td class="descripcionConError">${lineaGastosConErrores} </td>
         </tr>
    </table>    

<div class="separador"></div>


    <ul class="fila fila-1">
      <li class="descripcionConError" id="lineaMensajeError">  <***:mensaje code="etiqueta.presupuesto.ventanaInfoCierre.mensajeError" /> </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
var existeIngresoDepartamentoGestion = "${existeIngresoDepartamentoGestion}";
var existeGastoSinValidar = "${existeGastoSinValidar}";
var existeGastoConErrores = "${existeGastoConErrores}";

if (existeIngresoDepartamentoGestion === "false"){
    $("#lineaIngresosDepartamentoGestion").hide();
    }
else{}

if (existeGastoSinValidar === "false"){
    $("#lineaGastosSinValidar").hide();
    }

if (existeGastoConErrores === "false"){
    $("#lineaGastosConErrores").hide();
    }

if (existeIngresoDepartamentoGestion === "false" && existeGastoSinValidar === "false" && existeGastoConErrores === "false" ){
    $("#lineaMensajeError").hide();
}
</script>
```

Comentar que los valores que hay dentro de los td como por ejemplo ${lineaGastosConErrores} son valores traídos de un controller desde java. La variable digamos que contiene dentro "12 de 37". Pues querría que el número 12 apareciese en rojo.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: lo mas limpio seria que separaras el contenido en distintos tags, podrian ser dos `<span>` uno con un estilo aplicado para darle otro color

Comment: Klaimmore muchas gracias. Seguí tu consejo y funcionó. Lo que sí, hay que tener un poco de cuidado porque <span> tiene unas propiedades por defecto que deberemos de tener en cuenta y arreglarlos por ejemplo con css (por ejemplo font-size:14 y también viene con un margen izquierdo que en mi caso tuve que poner a 0 para que saliese bien alineado todo).